# .NET thread dies whenever object is disposed

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm running this code in its own thread, created using `new Thread()`.  As soon as `obj` is disposed the thread dies.  However, the thread execution shouldn't ever stop, because of the endless loop:

```
while (true)
{
   using (var obj = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
   {
      // do stuff
   }
   // never gets this far, thread dies
}
```

Why does this happen?  It's no different if I call `obj.Dispose()` explicitly.  Without disposing, the thread runs fine and continues indefinitely.

Is the CLR counting the number of object references held by the code, and killing the thread when they reach zero, despite the the loop?

Comment: What code is in `MyDisposable`'s `Dispose()` method?

Comment: Yes, what does `MyDisposable.Dispose` look like? Might that `Dispose` method possibly throw an exception? (What happens when you put a `try..catch` block around your `using` block?)

Comment: The disposable object is actually a Stream, returned by `HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()`.  I've updated the question because this might be relevant.

Comment: If I wrap the using block in a try/catch, no exception is thrown before the thread dies.

Comment: What they all said: wrap it in a try catch then if you can't figure out what is happening post the exception you get here.

Comment: @Neil no exception thrown, thread just dies :(

Comment: @Alexei yes, I create a new HttpWebResponse object each loop

Comment: @cxfx - Something weird is happening - is the rest of your program dying - are you running this in the debugger?  Make sureyou set break on all CLR exceptions when they are thrown to on in the Debug|Exceptions dialog.

Comment: @Neil yes, it's very weird. The rest of the process is fine, it's just this thread that dies. I'm running in the debugger, and it makes no difference if I set to break on CLR exceptions.

Comment: @cxfx replace you using block with a try..finally and manually dispose and see if you can spot the exact moment of death by tracing through...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The garbage collector will pick up and destroy the object as soon as there is no other references to the object.  So, if you call a method, and inside that method there is a local variable which references the thread, the thread will be killed as soon as (possibly later, depending on when the garbage collector runs) you leave the function.  The only way to ensure the thread keeps running is to maintain a reference to the thread.  This can either be done through a static variable, or through some other variable that does not go out of scope.

Comment: Thanks Kibbee. The thread is stored in a field of a WinForm, so should remain in scope for the duration of app.

Comment: `... destroy the object as soon as...`, well, sometimes not so soon.

Comment: Wrong. Threads root themselves [while they are running]. A unreferenced [by user code] thread will not be garbage collected.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is incorrect when it states,

> "The only way to ensure the thread keeps running is to maintain a
>   reference to the thread"

As Simon pointed out and per Microsoft,

> "It is not necessary to retain a reference to a Thread object once you
>   have started the thread. The thread continues to execute until the
>   thread procedure is complete."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx